# Byte Buddy's method delegation leads to StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow, byte-buddy, javaagents

I am trying to create an agent that proxies the methods in order to do some logic before and after the method. In order to do this I use Byte Buddy with method delegation.

Agent:

```
//Agent code before...
private static void instrument(String agentOps, Instrumentation inst) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default().with(new Eager())
            .ignore(ElementMatchers.nameContains("com.dvelopp.agenttest"))
            .or(ElementMatchers.hasAnnotation(ElementMatchers.annotationType(ElementMatchers.nameContains("SpringBootApplication"))))
            .type((ElementMatchers.any()))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder.method(ElementMatchers.any())
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class)))
            .installOn(inst);
}
//Agent code after...
```

Interceptor:

```
public static class Interceptor {

    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> superCall, @SuperMethod Method superMethod, @Origin Method currentMethod,
                                   @AllArguments Object[] args, @This(optional = true) Object me) throws Exception {
        //... logic
        Object call = superCall.call();
        //... logic
        return call;
    }
}
```

It works just perfect on a simple console app. But, when I have some common libraries in my classpath(e.g. simple Spring Boot project), it doesn't work as expected. It produces different errors, but most of them are connected to unexpected reflection like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/reflect/GeneratedMethodAccessor24
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:403)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:53)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:85)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:60)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:135)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog$original$snrPR67N(LogAdapter.java:102)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog$original$snrPR67N$accessor$5P1QZaof(LogAdapter.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter$auxiliary$pVmPc64S.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:126)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog$original$4Ty3vM8s(LogAdapter.java:79)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog$original$4Ty3vM8s$accessor$z3gv7aJK(LogAdapter.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$auxiliary$6cBoraQE.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:126)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog$original$MoDHp2B7(LogFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog$original$MoDHp2B7$accessor$VdtqA6Wx(LogFactory.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$auxiliary$ak9XEBl0.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:126)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog$original$MoDHp2B7(LogFactory.java:59)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog$original$MoDHp2B7$accessor$VdtqA6Wx(LogFactory.java)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$auxiliary$8JhBdK8k.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:126)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:194)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 39 more
```

As I can see, these errors are happening with objects that are proxies:

```
e.g. org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog$original$MoDHp2B7
```

I tried to debug that deeper and I found out that super method and origin have different classes. The "super" one has a Proxy class.

```
@SuperMethod Method superMethod, @Origin Method currentMethod
```

Is there a way to make delegation work with such objects?

Added:

On this Spring Boot 2 example(https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) there is a clear StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.MethodCallContext.getCaller(MethodCallContext.java:18)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:108)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.getSource(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource.getSource(MapPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.getSource$accessor$d92Pg8OK(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource$auxiliary$ATPz5tSr.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:122)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.getSource(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource.getSource(MapPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.getSource$accessor$d92Pg8OK(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource$auxiliary$ATPz5tSr.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:122)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.getSource(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource.getSource(MapPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.getSource$accessor$d92Pg8OK(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java)
at org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource$auxiliary$ATPz5tSr.call(Unknown Source)
at com.dvelopp.agenttest.Main$Interceptor.intercept(Main.java:122)
```

Comment: Bow does this relate to a StackOverflowError?

Comment: Yes, errors are different. Bug trying to Google them leads to StackOverflowError problem. I tried not to instrument this package and then I get something similar in Spring packages.

Comment: Added to the question StackOverflowError that happens when I test it with Spring project.

Comment: To me, this looks like Byte Buddy is correctly calling the super method of SystemEnvironmentPropertySource which is in MapPropertySource. This method does however calling itself which causrs the recursion.

Comment: If I exclude classes from instrumentation. E.g. change any() to .type((ElementMatchers.is(Main.class))) then everything works. That's why I think byte buddy conflicts with spring boot

Comment: Checked the same, but with Advices -    Advice.OnMethodExit    Advice.OnMethodEnter and got the same problem

Comment: then something else is off. advice retains the shape of a class. are you sure this is bound to the instrumented byte code?

Comment: Rafael, I am pretty sure it's connected to instrumented bytecode. Because when I exclude this and other classes, everything works fine. But, I should exclude a lot of classes from Spring because many of them have this problem

Comment: could ypu create a reproduction? i am sure there is an easy explanation.

Comment: Rafael, do you mean a little project to share?

Comment: Yes, some code that I can run that reproduces your problem. Please submit it to GitHub, to the issue tracker.

Comment: Yes, sure: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/585

Comment: @dvelopp did you have a chance to check answer from [byte-buddy contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572253/5728095), Rafael Winterhalter? It seems similar issue described.

Comment: That case allows you to execute/not execute your code on recursion method, but it doesn't control the flow itself. You anyway call super method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using wrong annotations, or functionality.

I'd recommend check more simplest case. For example replace your implementation:

```
    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> superCall, @SuperMethod Method superMethod, @Origin Method currentMethod,
                                   @AllArguments Object[] args, @This(optional = true) Object me) throws Exception {
        return superCall.call();
    }
```

with next one:

```
    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@RuntimeType Object value) throws Exception {
        return value;
    }
```

In this case you avoid of recursion call, but possible will get a chance to detect and analyze different issue, that is clear and has relation on your situation.

Possible you should pay attention on conceptual issue also. You know `java` developers using `Callable` object should never use `call()` directly.

Following API description for `@RuntimeType` it uses for mapping from one object to different one. New question appears: why do you need convert `callable` object? In which type it is going to be converted (are you sure that without Future wrapper you'll have an object there. There could be `null` that possible leads to your exception, isn't it?)?